# How can I separate variable and set the key to true for swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to separate the string in var into different vars and set key to true. For example

> var x = [English , Chinese , Maths] => "English":true "Chinese":true
>   "Maths":true

and push to firebase in order to get a data structure like:

> name:anon subject:{"English":true
>            "Chinese":true
>            "Maths":true}

What should I do ?

Comment: You can separate a string but you cannot make them a variable or many. 
But you can use these strings as Keys and set true as their value to key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
var x = ["English", "Chinese", "Maths"]

var subject: [String: Bool] = [:]
x.forEach { string in
  subject[string] = true
}
```

or

```
var subjectList = ["English", "Chinese", "Maths"]

var subject: [String: Bool] = [:]
subjectList.forEach { 
  subject[$0] = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [reduce(into:_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126956-reduce) method to enumerate the array and create a dictionary

```
 let x = ["English" , "Chinese" , "Maths"] 
 let result = x.reduce(into:[String:Bool](), { $0[$1] = true })
 print(result)//["Chinese": true, "Maths": true, "English": true]
 let valueToSend = ["name":"anon", "subject": result]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first remove duplicates from your array (or not do this if you are sure), map each item of the array to tuple with `true` as the second item, then use [`Dictionary.init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127165-init):

```
let result = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: Set(a).map { ($0, true) })
```